# how to query the rawcontacts ,excluding from the list of "not assigned" to any group in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, google-contacts-api, rawcontacts

I'm backing up and restoring my contacts, I want to query only those contacts, which the user sees in the contacts default application list. I'm using **samsung duos**, there is a group name called "Not assigned" in groups tab in default(**samsung**) contacts application.

Here is my query

```
  ContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                        projection,null, null, null);
```

With this I'm getting all the contacts which are present in "not assigned" group, but I don't want to access them. How do I filter that, I couldn't find the relation from where these contacts list are fetched. Does anyone know where you can find this so called "not assigned" group list in all samsung phones?